# Vlookup csv merge using batch file

Tags: csv, batch-file

- Groups.txt:

```
HFM_E_AHSM_FinRpt_Coor,,,xABC,Native Directory  
HFM_E_AHSM_FinRpt_Coor,,,xDEF,Native Directory  
HFM_E_AHSM_FinRpt_Coor,,,xGHI,Native Directory
```

- Reviewer.txt:

```
HFM_E_AHSM_FinRpt_Coor,Test
```

- Current Output:

```
Test,xABC,Native Directory  
Test,xDEF,Native Directory  
Test,xGHI,Native Directory
```

- Desired Output:

```
HFM_E_AHSM_FinRpt_Coor,Test,xABC  
HFM_E_AHSM_FinRpt_Coor,Test,xDEF  
HFM_E_AHSM_FinRpt_Coor,Test,xGHI
```

Would like to get the **same data** from **Groups.txt**, perform vlookup against **Reviewer.txt** and place **matching data** in **column 2**, then **bring in x values**.  Lastly **remove last column**.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load File1 as lookup table:
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (Reviewer.txt) do (
set "filename=%%~a"
set "col1_2[!filename: =_!]=%%~b"
 )

rem Process File2:
for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in (Groups.txt) do (
   set "filename=%%a"
   for /F %%f in ("!filename: =_!") do if defined col1_2[%%f] (
      echo !col1_2[%%f]!,%%b
     ) else (
      echo NoMatchingFilename,%%b
     )
  )
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How do I get to desired output, pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data doesn't include any spaces in col1 of Groups.txt,
so it's unclear why you do the string replacement `!filename: =_!`

Otherwise you need two changes

1. the asterisk in `for /F "tokens=1*  delims=,"` won't split further columns
   => `for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=,"`
2. col1 of groups.txt is in %%a but missing in the output.

---

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load File1 as lookup table:
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (Reviewer.txt) do (
set "filename=%%~a"
set "col1_2[!filename: =_!]=%%~b"
 )

rem Process File2:
for /F "tokens=1,2* delims=," %%a in (Groups.txt) do (
    set "filename=%%a"
    for /F %%f in ("!filename: =_!") do if defined col1_2[%%f] (
        echo %%a,!col1_2[%%f]!,%%b
    ) else (
        echo NoMatchingFilename,%%b
    )
)
```

yields:

```
> SO_55736556.cmd
HFM_E_AHSM_FinRpt_Coor,Test,xABC
HFM_E_AHSM_FinRpt_Coor,Test,xDEF
HFM_E_AHSM_FinRpt_Coor,Test,xGHI
```

Please note that `for /f` treats successive delimiters as only one.
If `groups.txt` contains content between `,,,` the column count doesn't match